# Switch from two sided to one sided type

Tags: double-sided, ieeetran

I'm trying to write a document using LaTeX using `IEEEtran.cls` (two sided by default). In my document, I have a portion of code, which has a big width. It would look nice to switch from the two sided mode to a one side, write the code and switch bag again. How can I do this in LaTeX?

I have tried `\setboolean{@twoside}{false}` but it doesn't work (no error, it just doesn't do what expected). Using `\onecolumn` before the code it works, but it begins with a new page.

There is any way to solve this? Btw, I'm using MiKTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you meaning "two column" rather than "two side"?

Comment: What do you mean by "code"? An equation? Actual source code?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `figure*` or `table*` environments (the contents will appear in the top of the next page where you write it); those environments can be used to typeset material that span both columns:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```