# Why there's a page difference between the title of the paper and the abstract?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, titles, abstract

Can you please tell me what causes a page difference between the title/authors and the abstract?

```
\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Spectral Clustering vs Wavelet Clustering: A Comparative Study}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{M. Jalal\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, R. Ramananda\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Electrical and Computer Engineering Department,%
                                           University of Wisconsin-Madison%
    \\\{jalal, ramananda\}@wisc.edu}

    }
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}


%****************************************************************************
% Abstract
%****************************************************************************
\onecolumn
\section{Abstract}
```

Comment: Issuing `\onecolumn` begins a new page in the IEEEtran class (which I'm assuming you're using). If this is for an IEEE conference, I wouldn't try to modify the class' default layout. If not, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59731/21344) for a method to typeset text spanning both columns.

Comment: I've just noticed: the reasoning is the same as in your other question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168558/why-each-section-is-shown-in-one-page-rather-than-in-the-same-page-when-i-use-o).

Comment: I am new to latex. Can you please tell me how to fix it without referring me to external links? thanks

Comment: the answer to your other question (linked in my second comment) fully explains the behavior and possible fixes.

Comment: Before you start making an abstract section and onecolumn issues. Remove those and write some stuff inside the `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` environment. That's how the style file formats an abstract.

Comment: @MonaJalal please remember to provide a MWE